# how to develop plug-in based application?

Tags: c++, qt, architecture, plugins

How to design(architecture) & write an application,in which plug-in can be released later. Can any one give some suggestion on the concepts that i have to concentrate to make the product more reliable & can be upgradable very easily? using QT & c++....

Comment: The best example I can think of would be Eclipse, and IBM wrote a paper about how that architecture was designed at http://www.eclipse.org/whitepapers/eclipse-overview.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Qt, you may find its support for plugins useful.

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/plugins-howto.html
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qpluginloader.html

That said, this is nowhere near what you get with the Eclipse RCP framework.

If your plug-ins are released on a different schedule than the host application, compatibility among versions is an issue. Maintaining binary compatibility between minor versions, as Qt itself has typically done, reduces the concern.

Testing supported version combinations in-house is desirable before they are tested by customers.

Answer (score 0):

Not for C++, but a plugin architecture for C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx